# Passign ID through login and then on to desired page in php

Tags: php, session, session-variables

this is the first question I've posted on here so I apologize if this is too much of a generalized question. Here is a brief description of what I want to happen:

When the user clicks on a particular link from the main page, it sends them to a dynamic page based on their id, however if the user is not logged in, they will first be brought to a login page, assuring they have the ability to access this part of the site. So what I need to happen is after the user logs in, the dynamic page gets generated based on the link's ID in the database.

I've tried looking into sessions but couldn't figure it out. Right now I can send the link ID through the URL to the login page, but can't transfer it over to the dynamic webpage. Let me know if you need to see code. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

```
The best way to do it is using SESSION.

Links Page:
<a href="item.php?id=1">Test</a>


Page Item.php

<?
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['userLogin']))
{
header("Login.php");
}
......

?>

Login Page.
You need to do a form in html with login and password
<?
session_start();
if($_POST['login']=='valid login' AND $_POST['password'] == 'valid password')
{
$_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];

header("Location: links")
}
?>

?>
```